# Youtube API key quota

Tags: youtube-api

I admit that I'm not the brightest guy when it comes to API usage, but I'm learning. I'm quite adept at building Wordpress sites, and I'm currently building one for a friend that is linking his Youtube channel to his blog site.  I'm using a plugin (one that is highly rated, mind you) and have set up a `YouTube API key`.

For a few days as I was building the site, trying out different themes, etc. You can see in my quota chart that queries were very low, far from the million that is the limit. But then, on Thursday Sept 21, they skyrocketed and my limit was reached and exceeded, shutting down the `API` until it reset at midnight. Then the next day, I didn't work on the site until the evening, and my query count topped over 650,000. I was the *only* person accessing the site, it is under construction and not available to the public yet.

I am linking to YouTube on two pages, the home page had a link to his YouTube live video (assuming he is live at the time of loading the page), and a page that lists all YouTube videos on his channel. I have noticed that if I go to the channel page, the query count goes up 5 units.  If I load the home page with the live video (or a different video if he's not live), the query count goes up 102 units.

I rarely ever visit the channel page. I have been working on the Home page for a few days, making tweaks here and there. But in order to max out my quota at 102 unit per page load, I'd be refreshing the home page over 9000 times. Something just doesn't seem right.

Am I missing something? Anyone have any insight into how my quota can be maxed out or a majority of it used with only ONE person accessing the site?

Here's a screen shot of my quota page:

[Clip from quota page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mBou.jpg).

Thanks in advance. The site goes live on Thursday, I really would like to keep the page without errors when that happens.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: If this is not the proper place for such a question, please refer me to where I am to ask such.  Youtube refers users to stackoverflow for support...or at least that is my impression.

Comment: Your question might be valid, but it isn't presented in a way that meets the site guidelines, nor in a way that makes it easy for anyone to help! Its a wall of text - please include a clear concise outline of your *specific* coding-related issue. This site is for coding-related questions, so you should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Its also expected that you have researched your issue beforehand, so include a summary of what you have already tried so we don't suggest them again.

Comment: Copied from the Youtube developers support page:

We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags.

I've asked the only way I know to ask.  It is not a coding question, but one concerning the youtube api.  this is the only place to ask such a question.  If it's not, then delete it.  I have researched to the point of going blind from reading for two days.  if you can't help, then don't respond...maybe someone else can.

Comment: As a new user, your question went through a quality review process, and your question doesn't meet the guidelines of the site as per my comment added during my review. I suggested how to improve it in order to help you 1. meet the guidelines and 2. make it easier for anyone else to help you with your problem. Besides not meeting the guidelines, you are highly unlikely to get help when your question is presented as it is.

Comment: Stack Overflow is **not** YouTube's support forum, whatever YouTube may claim. That does not mean you can't post a question regarding the YouTube API, but note that a wall of text without a clear indication of a [question related to programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) isn't exactly what defines a good question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a broad question, I will try to help. But note that it might be shooting in the dark.

On my own project that I did as a self project ( it is a youtube retro page site), on an average page load I have a quota of 14.
This is to a few api calls at the same time to populate the needed info.
So from my knowlage, I can assume a few things.

1: It is possible that someone has used/found your api key.
2: you are not using the correct calls for the task at hand.
3: Your script might have something that is running more times than expected.
4: Bad implementation of calls or scripts.
And lastly
5: I have seen it where search bots and page crawlers are indexing the pages and in doing so, use up quota.

These are not the only possible reasons, but from limited info, sound like a good start to look at.

Here is the page to look at [QUOTA LIMITS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

Comment: Thank you Tempus.  That's more than enough for me to at least begin to figure out what could be the problem.